# Python: Panda Series Attribute error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am implementing a DataFrame and i wish to generate a new column called 'm' from the previous data of the already declared columns.

I am getting the error ***"("'Series' object has no attribute 'df'", 'occurred at index 0')"***

This is the error that is occurring on the second last line of my code.

Pasting my code below:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np


#Create a Dictionary of series
d = {'Name':pd.Series(['Tom','James','Ricky','Vin','Steve','Smith','Jack',
   'Lee','David','Gasper','Betina','Andres']),   
   'Age':pd.Series([25,26,25,23,30,29,23,34,40,30,51,46]),
   'Rating':pd.Series([4.23,3.24,3.98,2.56,3.20,4.6,3.8,3.78,2.98,4.80,4.10,3.65]),
   }

df = pd.DataFrame((d),columns='Age','Name','Rating','New Column')

df_1=pd.DataFrame(d)

def value_mean(row):
    return (row.df['Age'].mean()*100*df['Rating'])

df_1['m']= df_1.apply(lambda row: value_mean(df["Age"]),axis=1)

print(df_1)
```

On printing df, i am getting this:

```
  Age    Name  Rating
0    25     Tom    4.23
1    26   James    3.24
2    25   Ricky    3.98
3    23     Vin    2.56
4    30   Steve    3.20
5    29   Smith    4.60
6    23    Jack    3.80
7    34     Lee    3.78
8    40   David    2.98
9    30  Gasper    4.80
10   51  Betina    4.10
11   46  Andres    3.65
```

However, when i am going to execute df_1['m'], i am getting this error.

```
("'Series' object has no attribute 'df'", 'occurred at index 0')"
```

Can someone please let me know where am i going wrong?

Comment: Your function accepts `row`, but you access `df`. Furthermore, the real issue is with `row.df`... why not just use `df_1['m'] = df_1['Age'].mean()*100*df_1['Rating']`?

Comment: Using `apply` in Pandas is bad practice.  If you could explain what you're trying to do (since your  code is nonsensical), it would help.